# Guardar en BBDD la fila seleccionada de un JTABLE

Tags: java

Tengo un pequeño problema...
Estoy intentando hacer que mi JButton "Guardar" me guarde en BD solo aquellas filas seleccionadas de mi JTable. el código que tengo es el siguiente:

```
    button = new JButton("Guardar");
    button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            connect cc = new connect();
            Connection cn = cc.conectar();


            try{
                int[] filasSelec = table.getSelectedRows();
                //for(int i = 0; i <= table.getSelectedRow(); i++)
                for( int i = 0; i < filasSelec.length; i++) {
                    String id = (String) table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i], 0);
                    System.out.println(id);
                {
                    PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO persona(pk_ci,nombre,apellido,tipo,telefono,contrasena,Estado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
                    pst.setString(1, table.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
                    pst.setString(2, table.getValueAt(i,1).toString());
                    pst.setString(3, table.getValueAt(i,2).toString());
                    pst.setString(4, table.getValueAt(i,3).toString());
                    pst.setString(5, table.getValueAt(i,4).toString());
                    pst.setString(6, table.getValueAt(i,5).toString());
                    pst.setString(7, table.getValueAt(i,6).toString());
                    pst.executeUpdate();
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,  "dato guardado correctamente");
                }
                }}catch (Exception e1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Error: "+e1.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

Mi jtable carga los usuarios existentes en la base de datos, para añadir un nuevo usuario cree un botón que le agrega una fila en blanco al jtable y ahí lo lleno con los datos del usuario nuevo. Al darle al JButton "guardar" este no guarda y devuelve el error de "clave duplicada para (un numero de usuario) for key primary" lo que sucede es que al momento de hacer clic sobre el botón guardar este comienza a leer el JTable desde el principio, es decir sobre los usuarios que ya existen en la base de datos y no sobre la fila que tengo seleccionada que sería el usuario nuevo

Comment: ¿Y cuál es el problema que tienes? ¿Qué hace tu código (lanza excepción, no hace lo que esperas, etc.)?

Comment: Mi jtable carga los usuarios existentes en la base de datos, para añadir un nuevo usuario cree un botón que le agrega una fila en blanco al jtable y ahí lo lleno con los datos del usuario nuevo. Al darle al JButton "guardar" este no guarda y devuelve el error de "clave duplicada para (un numero de usuario) for key primary" lo que sucede es que al momento de hacer clic sobre el botón guardar este comienza a leer el JTable desde el principio, es decir sobre los usuarios que ya existen en la base de datos y no sobre la fila que tengo seleccionada que sería el usuario nuevo.

Comment: Para completar la pregunta, rectificaciones, etc., es mejor darle al botón "editar" para añadir allí la información.

Comment: @SJuan76 Perfecto lo tendre en cuenta, es que soy nuevo aquí! Tienes idea de como puedo resolver mi problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for( int i = 0; i < filasSelec.length; i++) {
   // Esto lo haces bien. La i-fila seleccionada no es i, es filasSelec[i]
   String id = (String) table.getValueAt(filasSelec[i], 0);
   System.out.println(id);
   // Esta llave sobra. No hace daño, pero lía al leer el código
   {  
       PreparedStatement pst = cn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO persona(pk_ci,nombre,apellido,tipo,telefono,contrasena,Estado) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
       // Aquí, lees el dato de la fila i, en vez de filasSelec[i]
       pst.setString(1, table.getValueAt(i,0).toString());
```

Si tienes F filas y seleccionas S, `filasSelec` será un array de S posiciones. Pero `i` irá de 0 a S-1; para saber cuáles son las filas seleccionadas tendras que hacer `filasSelec[i]`

Comment: En efecto! muchas gracias estimado!